Wick's theorem proof for fermions
This is my first question. I am trying to prove Wick's theorem for fermions. I am currently using  Peskin and Schroeder's discussion, which is in section 4.7 (and uses section 4.3, where Wick's theorem for scalar fields is proven). I must say there are some fishy things about Peskin's 4.7 explanation. For example, I think spinor index are missing in all expressions. However, that is not what bothers me, but the proof itself.
The proof for the fermionic case relies on the one of the scalar field case. This proof is by induction. Using the definition of contraction between two fields $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$:
$C(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
[\phi_1^+(x),\phi_2^-(y)],  & \text{if $x^0>y^0$} \\[2ex]
[\phi_2^+(y),\phi_1^-(x)], & \text{if $y^0>x^0$}
\end{cases}$
It is proven the Wick's theorem for the $m=2$ case:
$T(\phi(x)\phi(y))=:\phi(x)\phi(y):+C(x,y)$
Now induction is used. Assuming it is true for $m-1$ and writing $\phi(x_i)=\phi_i$, we have:
$T\{\phi_1 ... \phi_m\}=\phi_1 ... \phi_m=(\phi_1^++\phi_1^-):(\phi_2 ... \phi_m+\text{All contractions of }\phi_2 ... \phi_m$):
Where we don't loss generality in the first step, because we can always relabel the spatial coordinates so that $x^0_{i+1}>x^0_i$ and this doesn't affect the fields inside the time ordering because we can rearrange them without changing the result. Now introducing $\phi_1^-$ inside the normal ordering is trivial, while $\phi_1^+$ gives more trouble. P&S doesn't specify in detail how to treat this term, but I have understood that for any term (for example the one without contractions):
$\phi_1^+:\phi_2...\phi_m:=:\phi_2...\phi_m:\phi_1^++[\phi_1^+,:\phi_2...\phi_m:]=:\phi_1^+\phi_2...\phi_m:+[\phi_1^+,:\phi_2...\phi_m:]$
And decomposing the second term into ones of the form $[\phi_1^+,\phi_{a_2}^-...\phi_{a_i}^-\phi_{a_{i+1}}^+...\phi_{a_m}^+]$ we can see using commutator properties iteratively (such as $[A,BC]=B[A,C]+[A,B]C$) that it results on all possible contractions involving only $\phi_1$. These are the reasonings that proof Wick's theorem for scalars.
Now, according to P&S, with the definition:
$C(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\{\psi_1^+(x),\psi_2^-(y)\},  & \text{if $x^0>y^0$} \\[2ex]
-\{\psi_2^+(y),\psi_1^-(x)\}, & \text{if $y^0>x^0$}
\end{cases}$
And using the rule of writing a (-1) for each fermionic interchange, Wick's theorem is still true and the previous proof is still valid. But I can't see why this is the case.
I proved the $m=2$ case, but the inductive step is difficult. It is doubtful for starters that we can do $T\{\psi_1 ... \psi_m\}=\psi_1 ... \psi_m$ without losing generality (sign differences might appear when we turn T(...) back to normal?). But even so, when we have to insert the $\psi_1^+$ into the normal order, I am lost. For example, I guess I have to do something like this:
$$\psi_1^+:\psi_2 . . . \psi_m:=-:\psi_2 . . . \psi_m:\psi_1^++\{\psi_1^+,:\psi_2 . . . \psi_m:\}$$
The first term is $(-1)^m:\psi_1^+\psi_2 . . . \psi_m:$ if I understood the definitions correctly, as a $(-1)^{m-1}$ arises for moving the $\psi_1^+$ past the $m-1$ fields. The second term is an anti-commutator, which doesn't have the same properties as the commutator, so I can't see why the rest of the manipulations of the proof would hold.
Can somebody help me understand how to prove this?

How should anyone without the book (at hand) understand the question? Consider for example to add the relevant equations with MathJax.

You are right. Done.

P&S often drop spinor indices to make equations less cluttered.

Thanks, but please do not use images for text and equations. See e.g. the discussion on meta. A tutorial for MathJax is here.

@TobiasFünke is everything alright now?

Well it's closed so you may have to wait or edit it again
